# Application to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, vb.net

**Scenario:** I want to develop an application.The application should be able to connect to my remote server and download data to the local disk , while downloading it should check for new files and only download the new ones simultaneously creating the required(new) folders.

**What am i doing?:** The app first checks for internet connection , if available pings the server to check if the server is active.Then it has to download the new files.

**Problem:** I have no idea how to compare the files in the server with the ones in the local disk.How to download **only** the new files from the server to the local disk?

**What am thinking?:** If i can create the exact folder structure(hierarchy) in the local disk as it is in the server...than i can download the new files accordingly to folders by maintaining some index file in both server and local disk.

Kindly help me guys..spare out some time..its urgent...Thanks.

Comment: Can you track on server side if file has been downloaded? Like when you finish downloading, call server method and tell it mark file as downloaded?

Comment: @ValBakhtin Many clients will be downloading simultaneously..so i will have to flag it as downloaded for every client(end-users) separately.

Comment: whats wrong with urgent?? why the down vote ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent `rsync`?

If you want to insist on rolling your own, checking for differing filestamp between files or comparing md5 hashes of the content would probably be a good start.

Comment: "checking for differing filestamp between files or comparing md5 hashes of the content would probably be a good start." ... what if new files are added to the server which do not exist in the local machine??

Comment: @user1150440: you would need to copy those over ;-) You'll need to deal with `deleted` files (on the server side) too. Basically the kind of stuff `rsync` does for you.

Comment: `rsync` seems interesting to me..and the app i am developing is linux based ...so i think its going to be useful ...thanks for the great info..on a different context..can i use `rsync` on a Android platform??